# 'Lost connection to device (sigterm)' error in Windows desktop app made by Flutter

Tags: windows, flutter

I wanted to create a Flutter Windows desktop application for the first time, so I set it up and tried to run it.

When the app started and changed the color of the appBar and hot reloaded it changed the color.
So far so good, but a few seconds later

```
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I get the above error message.
This is the behavior no matter how many times I do it.

I found some similar articles, but I don't really understand because the situation is slightly different.

Any clues would be helpful.

My Lenovo Windows computer has 4GB of RAM, does that matter?

Comment: It is frequent in devices which has less ram. Because of less ram the application which you launch, it status becomes not responding. Due to this, windows might close your app leading to losing connection to the device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I see.

We don't want to spend time on such errors, so we need a computer with sufficient performance.

Comment: Yeah, ram >= 8gb should be enough. But for good performance always prefer above 8gb (16gb). Also CPU should be more performant.